# Whatsapp Intent: Multiple images, each with a different caption

Tags: java, android, android-intent, whatsapp

I'm trying to send multiple images to Whatsapp via Intent, but each must have a different caption. Is this possible?

I can send multiple images at once, but cant set the text for each.

Sending multiple images with fixed caption:

```
Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "fixed caption");
whatsappIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mArrayListImagesURIs);
whatsappIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(whatsappIntent);
```

putParelableArrayExtra is capable of receiving an ArrayList of URIs, and correctly sends them in one action. But it cannot receive an ArrayList of Strings, because they are not parcelabes.

If I try this:

```
 whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mArrayListStrings);
```

Then no caption is sent.

Has anyone been successful at this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Sorry CommandSpace, no luck for me... Only one caption for images, does not matter if it is one or more than one. My solution was to add the caption to each image via Java, inside the bitmap... not what I expected at first, but solved my issue.